# how to remove +new from wp admin area

Tags: admin

I work on a project in which I want to remove +New link in WordPress admin bar. Actuly i want to replace 'new' to 'ADD Deal'. Is there any function in WP with this we can replace this text or how can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are asking is changing the text +NEW to ADD Deal.

This code is adjusted like that.

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'change_new_post_name', 999 );

function change_new_post_name ( $wp_admin_bar ) {
          //Removing +New
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'new-content' );
          //hyperlink for the new link. This can be anything. Currently it's default.
    $link = get_bloginfo('url').'/wp-admin/post-new.php';
          //Parameters to create a new node
    $args = array(
    'id'    => 'new-content', //re-creating the +New 
    'title' => 'ADD Deal',    //Giving it a different title
    'href'  => "$link"        // Above created link
);
$wp_admin_bar->add_node( $args );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For removing +New from admin menu bar and adding a new node to the admin bar, you can use the following code.

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wpse135424_remove_newpost', 999 );

function wpse135424_remove_newpost ( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'new-content' );
    $args = array(
    'id'    => 'your_page',
    'title' => 'Your Title',
    'href'  => 'Your Url'
);
$wp_admin_bar->add_node( $args );
}
```

Please check the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_node) for adding node.